# Gatsby.js, can't load tensorflow.js and bodypix

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, gatsby, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to run tensorflow.js at the moment in gatsby. I keep receiving this error,

```
warning Error from chokidar (/home/incompleteness_hewlbern/Documents/Code_Projects/AR_Work/esatta-app/node_modules/timers-browserify): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/incompleteness_hewlbern/Documents/Code_Projects/AR_Work/esatta-app/node_modules/timers-browserify/package.json'
```

This is with using this code,

```
import * as bodyPix from '@tensorflow-models/body-pix'; 

async function loadAndUseBodyPix() {
  const net = await bodyPix.load();
  // BodyPix model loaded
}
```

What is the issue? Is it todo with having an async function?

Thanks in advance,